# Spinner how to change the data

Tags: java, android

I initially have 2 spinners in my project. I want to change the data of the 2nd Spinner when the first spinner values are changed. Here's what I have tried.

```
Spinner subscription = findViewById(R.id.spinner_subscription);
    items_subscription = new String[]{"Daily"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_subscriptions = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items_subscription);
    subscription.setAdapter(adapter_subscriptions);

    payment_method.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position == 0){
                items_subscription = new String[]{"Daily"};
            }else if(position == 1){
                items_subscription = new String[]{"Monthly", "Annually"};
            }else if(position == 2){
                items_subscription = new String[]{"Monthly", "Annually"};
            }else{
                items_subscription = new String[]{"Daily"};
            }

            adapter_subscriptions.notifyDataSetChanged();
            subscription.setAdapter(adapter_subscriptions);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

And the above doesn't work. It only ads "Daily" on load, and when Spinner1 values change, the spinner2 values do not change. How can I achieve the following ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you changed the reference to the array `items_subscription` of your adapter when you reassigned it in inside `onItemSelected`, now your `adapter_subscriptions` doesn't have the same object as the array and you're modifying a data that the adapter has no knowledge about it. It's better to have an array list, clear it, and fill it with new data when they're changed then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
ArrayList<String> items_subscription = new ArrayList<>();
// add your objects to the list and initialize the adapter
// ...
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    items_subscription.clear();
    if(position == 0){
        items_subscription.add("Daily");
    }
    // ...etc

    adapter_subscriptions.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```